# WordPress добавить еще поля в легенду, при выводе новой записи

Tags: php, wordpress, settings

В админ панеле во вкладке  "записи" по умолчанию имеются поля для отображения  характеристик записи.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда делаешь сам новый тип записи, то в легенде появляется только заголовок и дата, и в настройках других полей нет. Не могу понять, где нужно искать инфу для настройки в этой области.

Подскажите пожалуйста,как можно добавить новые поля в легенду?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите где про это можно почитать?
Или может подаскажите, как это можно сделать?
В идеале я хочу убрать вообще заголовок, так как он для нескольких записей будет одинаковый, а хочу добавить краткое описание и картинку превью.

Comment: [manage_{post_type}_posts_columns](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/manage_-post_type-_posts_columns)

Comment: При создании кастомных типов они там появляются автоматом. Выходит ты криво создал свои "сервисы".